# KarbsETW is only able to process creation events from powershell

Tags: windows, events, etw

I am trying to compiler the code in https://blog.securehat.co.uk/detection-experiments/detecting-parent-process-spoofing-using-krabsetw which is supposed to detect process creation.
I see that the code is only able to detect process created by powershell.

Why is it so?

Comment: That is not the case. Compile and run. It sees every process start for the whole system.  The Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Process ETW provider is not specific to powershell.